# Free software for photo distortion (and morphing)

Tags: windows, gratis, photography

I'm looking for free windows software for photo morphing and/or distortion.

As people keep upvoting the existing suggestions, I am temporarily putting this at the top in bold: As far as I can tell, **neither paint.net nor the recommended gimp packages offer what I am looking for**, but feel to correct me if I missed something.

There are plenty of good morphing programs one can buy e.g. Adobe AfterEffects, Morpheus, AngelMorph, but I need a free one. Well done distortion is much more important than morphing, but the two often go together for obvious reasons. I include morphing software in my question because morphing software tends to also do distortion secondarily, even if it primarily advertises itself as morphing software.

**Clarifying Note**

My apologies as apparently I wasn't clear, I thought by pairing the term distortion with morphing it would be clear that I meant the sort of free form distortion that is also used in morphing software. By distortion and morphing I do not mean a handful of specific canned distortions (e.g. barrel distortion), I mean distortion of the sort that usually goes hand in hand with morphing, i.e. extremely free form distortion. In morphing one transitions a picture of a tiger into a cow which involves lots of warping. Hence morphing software usually also allows free form distortion of images. The sort of free form distortion usually available in morphing software is what I am after. There are many algorithms that can be used to smooth and interpolate such warping from key points or key segments the user moves, and they will obviously vary in quality.

Comment: Do you have a minimum list of types of morphs/distortions it needs to be able to apply?

Answer (score 7):

Depending on which distorts &/or morphs you need:

- [GIMP](http://www.gimp.org/) excellent free photo manipulation program with a number of morphing & distort tools plus [more to come](http://wiki.gimp.org/wiki/Roadmap) - *some under development features are already available if you are able to build it yourself from the git repository*.
  [image: GIMP Screen Shot]
- [G'MIC](http://gmic.sourceforge.net/) Command line tool allows a larger number of distorts and can easily apply the same distorts to multiple files.
- [GIMP](http://www.gimp.org/) + [G'MIC](http://gmic.sourceforge.net/gimp.shtml) adds G'MIC features to the GIMP user interface.
  [image: GIMP+G'IMC]
- For Lens & Barrel Distortion correction [Hugin](http://hugin.sourceforge.net/) Panorama Stitcher includes both.
- For mapping photos onto 3D shapes [Blender](http://www.blender.org/) 3D Modeller allows this but is probably overkill for your purpose as it is a full 3D modelling, rendering and animation package.

**All** of the above are free open source projects so you can, if desired, examine the source code to ensure that it is completely malware free.

Comment: Screenshots would be great :-)

Comment: Added a couple but without more detail of the type of distort/morph can't be more specific.

Answer (score 2):

[Paint.NET](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paint.NET) is a free image editor with layers designed to replace MS paint but then become very well-known and commonly used. It has distort feature and it also supports plug-ins so you can get new features easily.

> Paint.NET is free image and photo editing software for PCs that run Windows. It features an intuitive and innovative user interface with support for layers, unlimited undo, special effects, and a wide variety of useful and powerful tools. An active and growing online community provides friendly help, tutorials, and plugins.
>
> It started development as an undergraduate college senior design project mentored by Microsoft, and is currently being maintained by some of the alumni that originally worked on it. Originally intended as a free replacement for the Microsoft Paint software that comes with Windows, it has grown into a powerful yet simple image and photo editor tool. It has been compared to other digital photo editing software packages such as Adobe® Photoshop®, Corel® Paint Shop Pro®, Microsoft Photo Editor, and The GIMP.
>
> http://www.getpaint.net/

[image: Paint.NET]